Should we make a Chinese.SE WeChat 微信 group?
I'm just wondering if there would be interest in creating a WeChat group for Chinese.SE.  I'd love to see:

Chinese.SE users posting about their Chinese study plans, achievements, experiences, etc.  It's good motivation.
Updates on newly available resources.
Entertaining yet educational memes, graphics, jokes, comics.
Those little personal epiphanies you have along the way.  E.g. 门 = door and 闩 = ?.

I.e., a WeChat group to post things are basically off-topic for both Chinese.SE and meta.Chinese.SE, yet probably of interest to the Chinese.SE audience.  (And while there is a chat room, it's rather empty.  And it functions differently.)
E.g. CNN recently had an article: Which languages are easiest -- and most difficult -- for native English speakers to learn? (PS. the answer is Arabic; Japanese; Cantonese/Mandarin (2,200 hours each).)  This would be interesting to post.
So... just throwing this out there...
Question: Should we make a Chinese.SE WeChat 微信 group?

No.
The general recommendation is not to use or install WeChat unless absolutely necessary. Some might even suggest having a dedicated device just to run it if you do have to use it. I’m not really planning on getting into this on here but you can look into it on your own, if you so desire.
Chinese@SE does have its own chat room as you have pointed out. @SE isn’t going to support -or- have it’s name on any alternative means of communication.
That being said though: you could start your own discord server or slack room dedicated to Chinese learners. You could plug it here, we do have community ads as I’m sure you’re very well aware. 

Sorry if this comes across a little harsh, I tried softening my response as much as I could while writing it.

Ah okay, thanks for replying.  I wasn't mean anything official, but I can accept there's concerns about using WeChat.  (I guess I didn't think of it since everyone has WeChat here.)

@Becky李蓓 Honestly, just whip up something on Discord. I think that would work out much better for everyone.

Discord is blocked in China, which might be inhibitive.  I can use it on my laptop via VPN, but it's somewhat 麻烦.

@Becky李蓓 It might be worth your time to see how to get it installed on your handheld devices.
